# Moving records between 2 DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 GridViews and when I select the rows I'd like to throw the records from the DataGridView1 to the DataGridView2.

Code is below:
When I click the button it does not play all the items.

```
    stuList.Add(new Student() { id=1,Name = "Jacob", Age = 29, City = "London" });
    stuList.Add(new Student() { id=2,Name = "Zulia", Age = 31, City = "London" });
    stuList.Add(new Student() { id=3,Name = "Brandon", Age = 35, City = "London" });

    defaultDGV.DataSource = stuList;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in defaultDGV.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
        {
            string str = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            var record = stuList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Equals(str));
            newList.Add(record);
            stuList.Remove(record);

        }
    }

    newDGV.DataSource = defaultDGV.DataSource = null;
    newDGV.DataSource = stuList;
    defaultDGV.DataSource = newList;
```

I'm finding that the `var record = stuList.FirstOrDefault (a => a.Name.Equals (str));` is doing something I do not know.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what the code above has to do with “selected” cells. The code appears to loop through each row in a grid and add that row to another grid. A simple trace of your code will explain why you are getting the results that you show. Trace it and watch what happens to the grids rows when you “remove” one of the items from its data source… i.e. `stuList`.

Comment: The first time through the loop of rows in the grid, the first row contains the value “Jacob”. This row “Jacob” is added to the `newList` then removed from the grids data source `stuList`. Since the first item (Jacob) is removed from the list `stuList` the first item in the list is now “Zulia” and the second item is “Brandon”.

Comment: Therefore, when you loop on the second iteration… row 2 ie.. (row[1]) will be “Brandon”. The code adds “Brandon” to the `newList` then removes “Brandon” from the grids data source `stuList`. This leaves “Zulia” as the first row of the grid. Upon entering the third iteration of the loop, the check for row 3 (row[2]) will be null and therefore will not add anything to the `newList` and will then exit the loop. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JohnG, That even perfect your understanding, but I would not leave "Zulia" in DataGrid1, how can I do that?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The point in the previous comments was in reference to the posted code. The loop in the code `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in defaultDGV.Rows)`… is broken. You should clarify what you are asking. You may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Creating a MCV example would help… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)